# Why does if statement with request->only() not work ? (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

i have a problem with a if statement and i don't
know how to fix it. What i want to do is if someone puts in the correct
vCode, the user will be created. If the vCode is incorrect the user will not be created and the $message variable will be: vCode invalid.

But even when put in a correct vCode the message still says vCode invalid.
Here is my code:

```
public function store(Request $request) {

    $vCode = $request->only('vcode');

    if ($vCode == 'stackoverflow') {
        // request only the form-inputs with the names: firstname, lastname and email.
        $oUser = User::create($request->only('firstname', 'lastname', 'email')); 
        $oUser->createPassword();
        $oUser->setRole(2);
        $oUser->save();
        $message = $oUser->getFullname().'succesfully created';
    } else {
        $message = "vCode valid";
    }

    return back()->with('successmessage', $message);
}
```

Comment: Are you certain $vCode === 'stackoverflow'?

Comment: I don't see what is wrong with it. `dd($request, $vCode);` and see what is sent through the request and is getting assigned to `$vCode`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`$request->only('vcode')` returns an associative array with only one element in it.

If you'd had three things in the `only()` call, your results might have been:

```
$request->only('name', 'age', 'cheese');
// ['name' => 'Pingu', 'age' => '22', 'cheese' => 'gorgonzola']
```

But if you have only one element, you still get an array, it just happens to be smaller:

```
$request->only('vcode');
// ['vcode' => 'stackoverflow']
```

So you need to change your `if` condition:

```
if ($vCode['vcode'] == 'stackoverflow') {
    // should work
}
```

Or you could just get it as a single value:

```
$vCode = $request->input('vcode');
if ($vCode == 'stackoverflow') {
    // should work
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the normal call `input()` for a single item:  `$vCode = $request->input('vcode');`,  `only()` returns an array.

Also, do not use `==` for string comparison, use `===`.